# nginx Rewrite with Trailing Slash

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx with the following rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/feed/?$ /index.xml last;
```

When I try to access:

```
http://domain/feed/
```

I works great. But when I access:

```
http://domain/feed
```

It does not add the trailing slash.
I'd like to add a trailing slash automatically when I access the link above, anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rewrite ^/feed$ /feed/ permanent;`

`rewrite ^/feed/$ /index.xml last;`

Answer (score 0):

Try(if not real server_name):

```
rewrite ^/feed$ http://$hostname/feed/ permanent;
rewrite ^/feed/?$ /index.xml last;
```

or:

```
rewrite ^/feed$ /feed/ permanent;
rewrite ^/feed/?$ /index.xml last;
```